# Missing Ressources > Cloud platform on app script project

Tags: google-apps-script

Do you know why I don't have '**Cloud Platform**' under Resources menu dropdown on my app script project?

[image]

I have searched around the internet but I can't find any solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Most likely it is related to your sharing settings. Are you the creator of the script? Are you signed in with multiple accounts?

Comment: No, I am not the creator of the script but someone has shared it with me, what should be in sharing settings? Right now he has already shared a bunch of scripts with me but this problem is just for this one specific script

Comment: Is the script bound to a spreadsheet or alone standing? If the sharing settings include edit access - both for the script and spreadsheet (the latter in case of a bound script) and you are signed in into your browser with the email with which the script was shared - you should not encounter problems. You can also try to create a new copy of the script.

Comment: The script is alone standing, it works if I create a new copy of the script but why is that? I mean, the copy of the script is also an alone standing script or is it something relating to sharing access?

Comment: Possibly the owner gave you only view permission or the ownership changed after the file was shared with you. I believe that it was an exceptional background error which should not occur again as long as you get entitled edit permissions.

Comment: Okay I will ask the owner, thank you